# How can I specify a range in a formula?

Tags: excel

I know that a formula can be applied on a range of cells by utilizing an intermediate column, but can I directly specify a range in a formula somehow?

E.g., is it possible to do something like this, to get the sum of the results of dividing each cell in E12-E26 by each cell in C12-C26:

```
=SUM(E12/C12:E26/C26)
```

An answer, either positive or negative, would be accepted.

Comment: the rare triple cross-post... https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11482/how-can-i-specify-a-range-in-a-formula, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/209796/how-can-i-specify-a-range-in-a-formula

Comment: Wow. A triple cross! I think it would be less work to google the question and figure it out then crowd source the thing. But... I already knew the answer and hindsight is 20/20.

Comment: If you read the comments on the site where the question was originally posted, the community said that it was posted on the wrong site and advised that acceptable sites were this and another one. I was not aware that it was possible to flag it to be moved to a particular site. So, I complied by re-posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you are wanting to do with an Array formula or CSE formula (Different name for the same thing). To do this, enter:

```
 =SUM(E12:E26/C12:C26)
```

Then, instead of hitting "Enter" on the keyboard use Ctrl+Shift+Enter (CSE). This will put squirrely brackets around the formula and will apply the division to each pair in the range and then sum the results.

---

You could also use `=SUMPRODUCT()` for this, which essentially acts like an array formula, but with the Ctrl+Shift+Enter nonsense:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((E12:E26)/(C12:C26))
```

`Sumproduct` is useful since it will do logic inside the parantheses first across an array/range of cells then sum up the results. You can pull of some cool stuff with the formula, but it's also a beast and cat get out of control pretty easily.